# How to perform efficient vectorisation in numpy (memory constraints)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am dealing with a lot of data, stored in an `np.array` of size (3, n).

I need to perform, for each datum x: `xx.T` (to form a 3x3 matrix). So this would make n lots of 3x3 matrices. I then need to add the results of each of these matrices to form an overall 3x3 matrix.

I did this as follows: `np.einsum('ij,ki->jk', x, x.T)` which seems to work. But the problem is, my n is incredibly large (I'm dealing with very large images of many mega pixels), and this method results in a `MemoryError`.

Are there any other ways I can do this whilst maintaining a vectorized method?

Thanks!

Comment: Give us a measure of dataset sizes involved, i.e. `n` here?

Comment: You could simply do : `x.T.dot(x)`.

Comment: @Divakar: if the array has shape (3,n), wouldn't you want x.dot(x.T)?

Comment: @DSM Well then `np.einsum('ij,ki->jk', x, x.T)` won't give a `(3,3)` output. Something is not clear there.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  Maybe OP just meant "3 x n" in a general sense, not actually _shape_ (3, n).

Comment: Maybe that's the glitch. If the `einsum` is done the wrong way round you would expect memory problems if the "non-3" dim is so large

Comment: Apologies, let me be more clear. If x0 = [1,2,3], I would expect [1,2,3;2,4,6;3,6,9] from x0*x0.T (where x0 is the column vector representation). Then if x1 = [4,5,6], I would expect [16,20,24;20,25,30;24,3036] from x1*x1.T. The final output would need to be the sum of these, [17, 22, 27;22, 29, 36;27, 36, 45]. `np.einsum` seems to create each 3x3 matrix and store it in memory, and then add them together, which uses too much memory for my 16gb ram. Images are around 3MP.

Comment: @KeirSimmons: yeah, but if I'm following, your einsum should give you the same result as Divakar's `x.T @ x`, no?  And it (the latter, I mean) should be very speedy.

Answer (score 1):

Working from your comment:

```
In [465]: x=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
In [466]: np.einsum('ij,ik', x,x)
Out[466]: 
array([[17, 22, 27],
       [22, 29, 36],
       [27, 36, 45]])
In [467]: x=np.ones((10,3))
In [468]: np.einsum('ij,ik', x,x)
Out[468]: 
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.]])
In [471]: x=np.ones((10000000,3))
In [472]: np.einsum('ij,ik', x,x)
Out[472]: 
array([[ 10000000.,  10000000.,  10000000.],
       [ 10000000.,  10000000.,  10000000.],
       [ 10000000.,  10000000.,  10000000.]])
```

If the array becomes too big for memory, you could try chunking it:

```
In [479]: res = np.zeros((3,3))
In [480]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     res += np.einsum('ij,ik',x,x)
     ...:     
In [481]: res
Out[481]: 
array([[ 170.,  220.,  270.],
       [ 220.,  290.,  360.],
       [ 270.,  360.,  450.]])
```

Generally a few iterations over a complex task is faster than pushing the memory limits without any iterations.  At some point the memory management costs exceed the iteration costs.

---

This simple `einsum` is just as easily solved with `dot`, and potentially faster:

```
In [484]: x.T.dot(x)
Out[484]: 
array([[17, 22, 27],
       [22, 29, 36],
       [27, 36, 45]])
```

---

```
In [486]: x=np.ones((10000000,3))
In [487]: timeit np.einsum('ij,ik',x,x)
426 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [488]: x1=np.ones((50000000,3))
In [490]: timeit np.einsum('ij,ik',x1,x1)
2.14 s ± 15.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [493]: %%timeit
     ...: res = np.zeros((3,3))
     ...: x2 = x1.reshape(5,-1,3)
     ...: for i in range(5):
     ...:    x3 = x2[i]
     ...:    res += np.einsum('ij,ik',x3,x3) 
2.1 s ± 5.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So even though I'm not hitting a memory limit yet, chunking gives me a slight speed improvement. (though I'm not far from memory limits; a few left over items in the ipython history stack can push me over).

An just for comparison, the @ (same as `dot` for 2d)

```
In [494]: %%timeit
     ...: res = np.zeros((3,3))
     ...: x2 = x1.reshape(5,-1,3)
     ...: for i in range(5):
     ...:    x3 = x2[i]
     ...:    res += x3.T@x3
537 ms ± 9.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [495]: timeit x1.T@x1
530 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [496]: timeit x.T@x
106 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

At this size chunking does not help when using `dot`.